# Script for Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Anyone here who knows what script to use to lock certain cells in Google Sheet? This is what I want to happen:

1. Create a sheet that is shared with 20 other users.
2. When a certain cell filled in with values, the cell automatically locks.
3. The only person who can do the editing (if necessary) is the owner of the sheet.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I think the obvious solution for this is to actually protect the ranges.

You can read more about protection range in [this page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection).

You could create an [on edit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) and protect the edited range for every interaction:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  
  const ss = e.source;
  const range = e.range;
  
  
  // Logging the values of the edited rang and value
  Logger.log(range.getA1Notation());
  Logger.log(e.value);
  
  if(e.value != "" && e.value != null && e.value != undefined){
    
    // The actual protect
    const protection = range.protect().setDescription(range.getA1Notation());
    
    // Ensure the current user is an editor before removing others. Otherwise, if the user's edit
    // permission comes from a group, the script throws an exception upon removing the group.
    
    // Sometimes is difficult to get the user, checking every time
    const me = Session.getActiveUser();
    if(me != ""){ 
      protection.addEditor(me);
    }
    
    
    // As sometimes the `me` value could not be retrieved add the try-catch
    try{
      protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
      if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
        protection.setDomainEdit(false);
      }
    }catch(error){
      Logger.log("Could not remove editors");
      Logger.log(protection.getEditors());
    }
    
    // Indicate what ranges have been protected
    range.setBackgroundColor('red');
  }
}
```

The owner of the sheet and the person who edited the cell in the first place may be able to modify it.